# Working out of a vertex array for destrucible objects

Tags: rendering, low-poly

I have diamond-shaped polygonal bullets.  There are lots of them on the screen.

I did not want to create a vertex array for each, so I packed them into a single vertex array and they're all drawn at once.

```
| bullet1.xyz | bullet1.rgb | bullet2.xyz | bullet2.rgb
```

This is great for performance.. there is

```
struct Bullet
{
    vector<Vector3f*> verts ; // pointers into the vertex buffer
} ;
```

This works fine, the bullets can move and do collision detection, all while having their data in one place.

Except when a bullet "dies"

Then you have to clear a slot, and pack all the bullets towards the beginning of the array.

Is this a good approach to handling lots of low poly objects? How else would you do it?

Comment: Wouldn't using a linked list instead of a vector work well? Then you can just pull out that one item, without needing to shift everything else.

Comment: I thought about using a linked list, but the underlying data needs to be an interleaved array with guaranteed contiguous storage that can be passed to the drawing API (`glDrawArrays()`, in this case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then you have to clear a slot, and pack all the bullets towards the
>   beginning of the array.

Don't shuffle all the bullets down toward the beginning of the array;  just swap the last bullet into the newly cleared slot.  That way you don't need to repack the whole vector;  you only need to move a single element to fill the space that was made by the dead bullet.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing this !:)

Answer (score 3):

If the number of bullets is fixed at the start, then you can leave the vert data in the array. Create a second array that is a list of Booleans that represent each bullet. As a bullet dies flip the value in the second tracking array to false. Use this array as a filter for you vertex loop.

So if each bullet has 4 verts, the second array is 1/4 the size, with each boolean representing 1 bullet of 4 verts.